# Propositional logic proofs: Prove X ∧ (Y v Z) = (X ∧ Y) v (X ∧ Z)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, boolean-algebra

The question asks me to Prove X ∧ (Y ∨ Z) = (X ∧ Y) ∨ (X ∧ Z). Can somebody walk me through this proof?

The axioms we are allowed to use are:

- ∨ Identity
- ∨ null
- ∨ commutative
- ∨ associative
- ∨ distributive
- implication
- ∨ DeMorgan
- ∨ idempotent
- self implication
- double negation

Comment: Use distributivity.

Comment: You could show the forward implication and the reverse implication.  $X=Y$ if and only if $X\rightarrow Y$ and $Y\rightarrow X$

Comment: could either of you give me an example of how you would solve this proof using your strategies?

Comment: @Kyounge1 Suppose $X\land (Y\lor Z)$ is true.  Then $X$ is true and $Y\lor Z$ is true.  Then either $X\land Y$ is true, or $X\land Z$ is true.  Thus, $(X\land Y)\lor(X\land Z)$ is true.  This is the forward implication.  The reverse would be similar.

Comment: @gd1035 - the point of the exercise seems to be to use the axioms, rather than truth tables. The proposition should be true in any structure that obeys those axioms.

Comment: @mathguy I was interpreting gd1035's comment more as the outline of a proof in a natural deduction system, as opposed to truth tables.  Though given the formulation of the question, I still agree with the conclusion of your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
  X \land (Y \lor Z) & = (X \land (Y \lor Z))''               \\
                     & = (X' \lor (Y \lor Z)')'               \\
                     & = (X' \lor (Y' \land Z'))'             \\
                     & = ((X' \lor Y') \land (X' \lor Z'))'   \\
                     & = (X' \lor Y')' \lor (X' \lor Z')'     \\
                     & = (X'' \land Y'') \lor (X'' \land Z'') \\
                     & = (X \land Y) \lor (X \land Z)
\end{align}
$$

I used $\, '$ to denote negation (rather than $\lnot$) - easier on my fingers.

Can you tell which axiom from your list was used at each step? I believe I wrote the proof in such a way that only one axiom is used at each step (but perhaps the same axiom may be used more than once in the same step).